# Как преобразовать десятичное число в двоичное, восьмиричное, шестнадцатиричное представление и обратно?

Tags: perl, системы-счисления

Как средствами Perl отобразить число, например 77, в разных системах счисления как: 1001101, 115, 4d соответственно и выполнить подобные преобразования в обратном направлении?

Comment: Вашу правку в ответе убрал. Потому как printf к обратному переводу никакого отношения не имеет. `print 0xFF` отлично напечатает 255 так как в perl числа принято задавать так же как и в C и способность переводить числа _из текста программы_ по префиксам - это способность языка. Сравните: `print 0xFF` и `print "0xFF"` первое выведет 255, второе 0. И если вам извне программы (`$a=<>; printf("%d",$a);`) придет значение с префиксом 0x то никакой printf сам ничего не перекодирует ...

Comment: @Mike ну там пример и не для строковых "0x111", а как есть 0x111 числовых отображений в perl был. Ну не суть. Добавьте тогда Ваше пояснение, о том как задаются числа в perl и в каких случаях их можно и не переводить, например число 101 будет воспринято как восьмиричное, если добавить 0 впереди: `print 0101;` и т.п. в Ваш ответ.

Comment: Написал конечно, хотя мне обычно в голову не приходит это писать ибо в половине существующих языков это так и оно кажется само по себе разумеющимся и относится не к вопросу перевода из одной системы в другую (ни одну переменную полученную как угодно вы без функций не переведете), а к области "указание констант в тексте"

Comment: @Mike спасибо. Ну это понятно, но зато теперь ответ стал более энциклопедичным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [`printf()`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf) абсолютно аналогичной функции языка C:

```
my $a = 77;
printf("Двоичное: %b, восьмеричное %o, шестнадцатиричное %x\n", $a, $a, $a);
```

Если число надо получить в строковой переменной, а не вывести на экран, то есть аналогичная функция `sprintf()`.

Для перевода входящих данных в десятичную систему счисления из других систем счисления следует использовать:

- Из шестнадцатеричной системы счисления `hex()`
- Из восьмеричной - `oct()`
- Из двоичной - прямой функции не существует, можно добавить к началу значения префикс `0b` и использовать `oct()` (`$a="00100111"; print oct('0b'.$a);`)

В тексте программ числа можно явно задавать в разных системах счисления они будут переведены в десятичную систему автоматически на этапе компиляции программы, например:

- Шестнадцатеричные 0x5F
- Восьмеричные, с ведущим нулем при условии, что ни одна цифра не превышает 7: 0752
- Двоичные 0b011101